# Error when opening infopath forms - errorcode 0x82000006(SharePoint Online).Please help!

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions, infopath, forms-services

I have been opening infopath forms before without any issues but suddenly i'm getting this error below:

The SOAP response indicates that an error occurred on the server:

```
Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.
<detail><errorstring xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
    List does not exist.
    The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user.
    </errorstring><errorcode xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">0x82000006</errorcode></detail>
```

Any ideas why this is happening?
THanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can troubleshoot this issue as following:

1. Make sure that the account who open the InfoPath form has enough permission to access the “not exist” list.
2. Try to customize the InfoPath form without change via clicking “Customize Form” button and republish it, check again.
3. If the issue still occurs, I suggest you check the ULS logs, which would tell you more information and tips about the issue.

Comment: I can't test the 3 option as i'm on SharePoint Online

Comment: Thanks Hellofiona.. I can open up the form via clicking “Customize Form” button and republish it, check again.But not by clicking through "Customize in infopath" in the top ribbon.When i use the top ribbon i get the same error